# Compute fields quantities from one model to another - Odoo v8

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo-8, odoo

Consider these four models:

```
class bsi_production_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order'

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Production Date")
    production_type = fields.Selection([
        ('budgeted','Budgeted'),
        ('nonbudgeted','Non Budgeted'),
        ('direct','Direct Order'),
    ], string='Type of Order', index=True,  
    track_visibility='onchange', copy=False,
    help=" ")
    notes = fields.Text(string="Notes")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.production.order.lines', 'production_order', states={'finished': [('readonly', True)], 'cancel': [('readonly', True)]}, string="Order lines", copy=True)
    print_orders = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order', 'production_orders', string="Print Orders")

class bsi_production_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.production.order.lines'

    production_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', string="Production Orders")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Float(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Float(string="Consumed quantity")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func")

    @api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
    def _remaining_func(self):
        if self.qty or self.consumed_qty:
            self.remaining_qty = self.qty +(-self.consumed_qty)

class bsi_print_order(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order'

    name = fields.Char('Reference', required=True, index=True, copy=False, readonly='True', default='New')
    date = fields.Date(string="Print Date")
    origin = fields.Char(string="Origin")
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    order_lines = fields.One2many('bsi.print.order.lines', 'print_order', string="Order lines")

class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

    print_order = fields.Many2one('bsi.print.order', string="Print Order")
    production_orders = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order")
    isbn = fields.Many2one('product.product', string="ISBN", domain="[('is_isbn', '=', True)]")
    qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity")
    consumed_qty = fields.Integer(string="Quantity consumed")
    remaining_qty = fields.Float(string="Remaining quantity", compute="_remaining_func")

    @api.onchange('qty', 'consumed_qty')
    def _remaining_func(self):
        if self.consumed_qty or self.qty:
            self.remaining_qty = self.qty +(-self.consumed_qty)
```

So, production order has production order lines, and print order has it's order lines too (One2many `order_lines` fields)

There is a method on both of them, which are both called `_remaining_func_`.

These are OK for `remaining_qty` fields, but `consumed_qty` should be inter-related between production.order and print.order.

So, for example, if `qty` on `bsi.production.order.lines` is 10, (There are other methods which create a `bsi.print.order` from production order), and on `bsi.print.order` I put on `qty` the value 5, the original 10 should be 5 on `bsi.production.order.line`, I think with a similar method like `_remaining_func_` I can achieve this, but I'm kind of confused on how to do this between the two models.

Any ideas?

If further explanation is needed, please let me know.

Comment: You have somes mistakes in this code, for example, your compute methods must have the decorator `@api.depends` with the fields whose modification will trigger the method (you are using `@api.onchange`). And the field `consumed_qty`, do you want it editable but at the same time computed, or you get by on making it editable only in `bsi,print,order,lines` and computed in `bsi.production.order.lines`?

Comment: They shouldn't be editable, mmm ok, gonna change to @api.depends , but the point is that when bsi.print.lines change, bsi.production.lines should too, but it's very confusing, Idk what You think about that.

Comment: Okay, yes, also it has some problems because it should loop through records, so in this way they aren't looping anything, if I add more than one record on line, it throws 'Expected singleton', gonna change that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is impossible to manage unless the relationship between `bsi.production.order` and `bsi.print.order` is 1:1, but in your case it seems that a production order can have many print orders. I give you the example:

You could create a `Many2one` field in `bsi.print.order.line` pointing to `bsi.production.order.line`:

```
class bsi_print_order_lines(models.Model):
    _name = 'bsi.print.order.lines'

    po_line_related = fields.Many2one('bsi.production.order.lines', ondelete='cascade', string="Production Order Line Related")
```

And each time a print line is created, you can easily create the related production line (you have all data you need):

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    print_line = super(bsi_print_order_lines, self).create(vals)
    po_line_vals = {
        'production_order': print_line.print_order.production_orders.id,
        'isbn': print_line.isbn,
        'qty': print_line.qty,
        'consumed_qty': print_line.consumed_qty,
        'remaining_qty': print_line.remaining_qty,
    }
    po_line = self.env['bsi.production.order.lines'].create(po_line_vals)
    return print_line
```

But you have to do the same the other way round (this time overwriting `bsi.production.order.lines` ORM create method), and here you find the problem:

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    po_line = super(bsi_production_order_lines, self).create(vals)
    print_line_vals = {
        'production_orders': po_line.production_order.id,
        'po_line_related': po_line.id,
        'isbn': po_line.isbn,
        'qty': po_line.qty,
        'consumed_qty': po_line.consumed_qty,
        'remaining_qty': po_line.remaining_qty,
        'print_order': '???????'  # You cannot know which print order you have to write here since a production order can have several ones...
    }
    print_line = self.env['bsi.print.order.lines'].create(print_line_vals)
    return po_line
```

If the relationship between `bsi.production.order` and `bsi.print.order` was 1:1, you could get the print order with `search` (because you would be sure that is going to return only one record):

```
@api.model
def create(self, vals):
    po_line = super(bsi_production_order_lines, self).create(vals)
    print_order = self.env['bsi.print.order'].search([
        ('production_orders', '=', po_line.production_order.id)
    ]).ensure_one()
    print_line_vals = {
        'production_orders': po_line.production_order.id,
        'po_line_related': po_line.id,
        'isbn': po_line.isbn,
        'qty': po_line.qty,
        'consumed_qty': po_line.consumed_qty,
        'remaining_qty': po_line.remaining_qty,
        'print_order': print_order.id,
    }
    print_line = self.env['bsi.print.order.lines'].create(print_line_vals)
    return po_line
```

And this way you would have your production lines and print lines related, and you would have to overwrite `write` and `unlink` methods too to control when a line is modified or removed, do the same for its "twin" (it would be easy to find it thanks to the new `Many2one` field named `po_line_related`).

Of course it would not be a beautiful solution but I think it is the only one (using Odoo API) for your Entity-Relationship Diagram.

Comment: I'll give it a try Thank You very much, but wow, very complex eheh